# Using void pointers: void **ptr... how to modify the value of a shared memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, posix

I'm trying to use a function:

```
void Mem::Attach(void **address)
{
   *address = NULL;
   if ((*address = shmat(memid, *address, 0)) == (void *) -1)
    perror(" stuff .... ");
}
```

The shared memory class:

```
class Mem {
   private:
        int memid;
   public:
         Mem(key_t key, int dimension);
         void Attach(void **adress);
         void Detach(char *adress);
         void Libere();
};
```

So essentially this is a wrapper to use shared memory between processes in Linux (with system v).

So I'm calling Attach() this way:

```
void *ptr_shared;                        
mem.Attach(&ptr_shared);
```

My current understanding:

- **void address is a pointer to a pointer ( *address ).
- *address is a pointer that shmat() will point to the shared memory block.
- So if I want to assign a value to that memory block (the key I got was for a block of a single int when I created my Mem object), I want to change the value to which *ptr_shared points to.

But if I try to do, say:

```
*ptr_shared = 42;
```

Then I get a SIGSEGV error.

What is wrong? Is it my understanding of pointer or is the problem with how I'm trying to use system v?

EDIT: Following Miles' comment (and John's to an extent). If I wanted instead Attach to return a pointer to the shared memory segment... how would I manage its type? When I created the shared memory segment, I used the size of an int. So... this would meant I absolutely have to assign only int into that segment, therefore the returned pointer type would have to be int? However, other memory segment may be created to contain chars... so in that case how do I manage the unknown type of the return pointer from Attach() that depends on the size of the mem segment?

I'm from a Python background, so we don't do types much....

Comment: Why not have `Mem::Attach` return a pointer to the shared memory segment?  That out parameter is just obfuscating things.

Comment: `*ptr_shared = 42` won't compile if it's declared as `void *ptr_shared`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: so... can I cast it as something? Or should this just not be a void ptr to begin with?

Comment: Strongly suggesting to save you'r time and use [boost interprocess](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/interprocess/)

Comment: @VictorGubin: Unfortunately that's not possible, as it's an assignement and we HAVE to use system V. Otherwise would glad to do that, took me ages just to figure out what shmat shmid etc... do.....

Comment: @Francky_V you can use use System V memory using `#include <boost/interprocess/managed_xsi_shared_memory.hpp>`. As well as many another things you will need. Check the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_shared_memory)

Answer (score 0):

> If I wanted instead Attach to return a pointer to the shared memory segment... how would I manage its type? When I created the shared memory segment, I used the size of an int. So... this would meant I absolutely have to assign only int into that segment, therefore the returned pointer type would have to be int? However, other memory segment may be created to contain chars... so in that case how do I manage the unknown type of the return pointer from Attach() that depends on the size of the mem segment?

You could cast your pointer to any ordinal type as long, as there is enough memory to hold its data:

```
void *ptr_shared;                        
mem.Attach(&ptr_shared);
char* someData = reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptr_shared);
*someData = 'f'; 
++someData;
int* otherData = reinterpret_cast<int*>(someData);
*otherData = 11;
```

Casting to dynamic type, like `std::vector` will end badly however.